# RVM gemset create isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

The created gemsets don't show up

```
    root@host:/# rvm gemset create foobar
    'foobar' gemset created (/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8@foobar).
    root@host:/# rvm gemset list

    gemsets for system (found in /usr/local/rvm/gems/system)
       *

    root@host:/#
```

why is that? help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to create a gemset for the system ruby, which RVM has no control over.

You need to `use` a ruby version before you create the gemset. I use 1.8.7 as an example here, but this will depend on which rubies you have installed.

```
rvm use 1.8.7
rvm gemset create foobar
```

Now you get:

```
$ rvm use 1.8.7
Using /Users/dougal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334
$ rvm gemset create foobar
'foobar' gemset created (/Users/dougal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@foobar).
$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.8.7-p334 (found in /Users/dougal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334)
   foobar
   global
   rails3
```

Comment: the problem i'm having is i think the system is on ruby 1.8.7 because that's what i get from rails -v is there a way to install the same ruby version in rvm as the system but with it's own gemsets?

Comment: `rvm install 1.8.7`. You might also want to specify the patch number to match your system ruby. In my case this is `rvm install 1.8.7-p174` (Snow Leopard).

Comment: i just did. rvm install 1.8.7-p249; rvm use 1.8.7-p249; rvm gemset create rails2; rvm gemset list...... nothing...

Comment: Hmm, I'd go through the RVM install procedure again, it sounds like you have missed something.

Comment: i added the line in the installed guide to .bashrc and logged back in and it's working :)

Comment: Great. I've missed it out the first time, easy to do.

Answer (score -4):

I have found that if you need 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 using the former for any applications by install it as part of the system and then installing 1.9.2 in your user directory and then point bash to the 1.9.2 version and using them separately is far better than trying to wrestle with that buggy POS named RVM.

It may work now, but sometime soon it will break when you install another Ruby or Gem and you will be back fighting it.

This works great for me as I use 1.8.7 for Kile, 1.9.2 and JRuby for my projects and RVM broke something every time I needed a new gem or update something. RVM is a good idea that was poorly implemented.

Comment: Poorly implemented? Once the install docs are followed it works perfectly for hundreds of people. In general I ignore the system ruby, and use an RVM installed Ruby by default in the terminal.

Comment: It doesn't work and that is the point. In my setup, I don't need a buggy layer between me and Ruby. For all intents and purposes 1.8.7 doesn't exist for me, yet the only program I use that depends on it happily uses it and 1.9.2 is ALWAYS what I get when I type in ruby in bash. I never have gem conflicts with 1.8.7 or JRuby and I don't ever have to fear something will break when I update or have to jump through hoops to use JRuby like I do with RVM. You can cry all you want that I called it poorly implemented, but facts are facts.